# How to get vector length in Ada?

Tags: ada

Example source code http://www.waratuman.com/2010/06/02/vectors_in_ada/

```
with Ada.Containers.Vectors;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
with Ada.Text_IO;
use Ada.Containers;

procedure Euler3 is

    package Integer_Vectors is new Vectors(Natural, Integer);

    Numbers : Integer_Vectors.Vector;
    Cursor : Integer_Vectors.Cursor;

begin

    -- Get some content
    Integer_Vectors.Append(Numbers, 43);
    Integer_Vectors.Append(Numbers, 44);
    Integer_Vectors.Append(Numbers, 45);

    Cursor := Integer_Vectors.First(Numbers);
    while Integer_Vectors.Has_Element(Cursor) loop
        Ada.Integer_Text_IO.Put(Integer_Vectors.Element(Cursor));
        Ada.Text_IO.New_Line;
        Integer_Vectors.Next(Cursor);
    end loop;

end Euler3;
```

How to get `Integer_Vectors` length from code above?

Comment: Note that the reference gives this as an example of how awkward iteration is in Ada; Ada2012 has improved this with [new generalized iterators](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-5-5-2.html#p14), `for N of Numbers loop ...`

Comment: wow, that's nice ^_^

Comment: but the `cursor` version (1-5 seconds) whole lot faster than `for of` (16-24 seconds) http://kokizzu.blogspot.com/2015/03/prime-number-generator-benchmark.html

Comment: If you had browsed the section of the language reference manual describing the package `Ada.Containers.Vectors`, it should be obvious.

Comment: And where would that be, I just learned Ada for 10 minutes XD

Comment: For example: http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-18-2.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, found it

```
Integer_Vectors.Length(Numbers)
```

or, more neatly,

```
Numbers.Length
```

Comment: It is time to learn to read ARM (Ada Reference Manual) - especially Annex A :)